# neocomplecache&clang complete installed: code complete work for cpp file, whereas doesn't for c file

Tags: vim, clang, vim-plugin

I have installed the vim plugin neocomplecache and clang complete and the patch of them named neocomplecache_clang_complete.

Also, I installed the clang to make clang complete works.

A pure c file named: test.c

```
typedef struct student
{
     int age;
     char name[20];

}Stu;

int main()
{
     Stu Kevin;
     Kevin.
}
```

After pressing the dot after "kevin" then "User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found" pops up.

A pure c file named: test.cpp

```
class Stu
{
     int age;
     char name[20]
};

int main()
{
     Stu Kevin;
     Kevin.
}
```

The members age and name pops up correctly.

I have checked the set omnifunc.  It is the same value on two above scenarios

Is anyone able to find out what's going on here?

Feel free to let me know if you need more info, such as my .vimrc

Comment: This is not directly related but apparently there is a new completion plugin in town : http://val.markovic.io/blog/youcompleteme-a-fast-as-you-type-fuzzy-search-code-completion-engine-for-vim

Comment: thanks for your reply. maybe i will get a try the new plugin you said.